# Generating cursor query dynamically

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I want to generate a cursor query dynamically based on few pl-sql variables used in same script. Consider a example

```
1. DECLARE
2.     emp_id number(12);
3.     CURSOR empList_cur is select emp_id from employee;
4.     
5. BEGIN
6.      LOOP
7.         FETCH empList_cur Into emp_id ;
8.         EXIT WHEN customerList_cur%NOTFOUND;
9.         CURSOR activityList_cur is (select empDetails from empDet where empNo=:emp_id)
10.     END LOOP;
11. END;
```

I want to use the value of emp_id retrieved from one cursor into other sql query as in line 9 in above code snippet.

What if correct syntax for same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You query is just accepting a value dynamically, and not a Dynamic SQL itself.

```
DECLARE
    l_emp_id number(12); /* Don't use the column name itself as variable name */
    CURSOR empList_cur is select emp_id from employee;

BEGIN
     LOOP
        FETCH empList_cur Into l_emp_id ;
        EXIT WHEN customerList_cur%NOTFOUND;
        FOR I IN (select empDetails from empDet where empNo=l_emp_id)
        LOOP
           /* you can simply use the variable here , 
             and using a Cursor here is not efficient */
        -- Other statements
        END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
 END;
```